# Drop-down menu disappears on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a problem with my drop-down menu which disappears as soon as I hover over it. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Menu */
header>hide:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: black url(burger.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header>nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 193px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 999;
}

header>nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header>nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(menu.png) no-repeat top right;
  background-size: contain;
}

header>nav>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 1em; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 59px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  width: 60%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

header>nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(146, 0, 0);
}

header>hide:hover + nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header class="clearfix">
<!-- Menu  -->
<hide></hide>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">123456</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">123456</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">123456</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">123456</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gmeayqLy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the menu from hiding as you try to hover over the link items, you need to add one more CSS rule with `:hover` that makes the menu visible when you are hovering over one of the links.

This can be done by adding the following CSS:

```
header>hide:hover + nav,
header>nav:hover {
        display: block;
 }
```

Note the `header>nav:hover` which I have added. That ensures that the `nav` element is visible when you hover over it.

Here's the link to updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmeayqLy/1/

Answer (score 2):

hint regarding this issue, sometimes make sure there’s no gap between the top li item and the sub list, for example, if you specify a margin for the top li item, can cause a problem, removing margin solve mine.